# How to resolve “DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved to a type"?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to run my first project with Appium on Eclipse and getting this error,

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved to a type
>     DesiredCapabilities cannot be resolved to a type
>
> at base.main(base.java:17)
>
> Error: Unable to initialize main class base Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver

```
package Auto;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base2 {

    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> dc() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver;

     File f = new File("src");
     File fs = new File(f, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
     DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

     dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "DSEmulator");
     dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"uiautomator2");
     dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
     driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);

        return driver;
    }
}
```

Can someone point me what I must add to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the same code on my machine and it worked perfectly fine. This means that the problem is not with your code. Unresolved compilation problems generally occur whenever there is some problem with the jars referenced by your project. I would suggest you to remove all existing jars from the project build path, and then add them back carefully ensuring that you have all the required jars and then try re-runnning your code.